# .gdbinit isn't being read by gdb on mac osx lion

Tags: macos, configuration, gdb

i have a .gdbinit file in my home directory (i know this because i have hidden files visible in the finder).

but for some reason its not reading it. well its not showing any user defined commands. any reason why gdb would be ignoring this file? and is there a way for me to fix it?

I'm on osx lion if that helps

Comment: What does `cat ~/.gdbinit` show when executed in a terminal?

Comment: Would also be interested in seeing the result of ls -la@e ~/.gdbinit

Comment: its working fine now. for some reason it was incorrectly reading the config. mark this as an answer so i can close it @EmployedRussian

Comment: Can't mark a comment as an answer. However, you can answer your own question and then mark it as an answer after a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a malformed config. A valid one fixed the issue